# Realtime Database Firebase Function trigger deployed from VSCode

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to this realm of programming and I was running into some issues not with deploying my Firebase Function to my Firebase Project but testing the function itself and its execution.
The following is a test code I am using that should log the response when this testTrigger has been created with new data. But no luck, for some reason the deployment is successful but when I look at the logs they're just notice logs that the deployment was successful, no execution logs. Anyone have any tips, I am quite lost.
Please let me know if you need more information!
Thanks ! :)

My code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://databaseurl123.firebaseio.com/"
});

exports.checkDatabaseTrigger = functions.database.ref("/testTrigger")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log("data added testTrigger:", snapshot.val());
      return null; 
    });
```

dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --fix",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Steps that I have followed:

1. I deploy this very index.js script
2. On my Firebase Functions I wait for the update of the function
3. Then I go to my Realtime Database specifically this URL
4. I then create the node and immediately type in a string of text like "Hello, World"
5. Finally, I check the logs for any execution logs but to no avail

Hopefully, this is what you were looking for?

I have also tried to vary my index.js to call a 2nd gen cloud function but I get even more errors...

Comment: Please edit the question to include the specific steps you use that you believe should trigger this function.  We should be able to follow your instructions to reproduce the issue. If you have client code that creates the node, show it.  Of if you're doing something in the console, explain that and show a screenshot. Keep in mind that the node must be completely new in order for the function to trigger.

Comment: To write a log from your function use the logging module provided by firebase or if you want to use console.log for logging from your function you have include a package provided by firebase.

Refer to this doc for more information on logging.   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?gen=2nd

Comment: You should not need the `const admin = require("firebase-admin");` nor the call to `initializeApp` for that import. Instead, the function will be triggered by the (default) Realtime Database instance for the project, so that's what you'll have to create data in.  --- Once you've fixed that, can you tell us how you try to trigger the function? What exact data do you create in what path in the database?

Comment: I used the const admin = require("firebase-admin") and the initializeApp to call a particular URL within my database not my default URL. However, when I tried this on my default URL it worked. So my issue is now is getting it to work for a particular URL other than my default one!
Thanks for the help!!